# Change values between two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of 4 `int`s, and I need to replace them with values of another array. For example: I have an array `{5,3,7,2}`, and I need to replace the values and get array `{2,7,3,5}`.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int array[] = new int[4];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 4;
    array[2] = 3;
    array[3] = 7;
    int swapArray[] = new int[5];

    for (int j = 3; j > 0; j--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            swapArray[j] = array[i];
            System.out.print(" " + swapArray[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't change values, just repeats it 3 times.

Comment: why do you have two arrays of different size?

Comment: also, do you mean replace or rearrange?

Comment: i need to rearrange. Fixed defferent sizes of arrays , ty :D

Comment: what is the logic for rearranging? do you just want to rotate the array by a few positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want to reverse the array. You could do it in place like,

```
int[] arr = { 5, 3, 7, 2 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
  int t = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
  arr[arr.length - i - 1] = t;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Or, you could copy it to a new (reversed) array like,

```
int[] arr = { 5, 3, 7, 2 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr2[arr2.length - i - 1] = arr[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
```

Both examples output (the requested)

```
[5, 3, 7, 2]
[2, 7, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you, mate, but can you explain me
arr2[arr2.length - i - 1] = arr[i];
Which value it picks? As i understand, at first iter. it picks third value...cant understand

Comment: In the first example, it swaps each value by iterating the first half of the array. Swapping each value with the value from the end (minus the current index). In the second example, it copies each value from the end of the second array to the current index in the first array.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this :

```
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int array[] = {1,4,3,7};
    int swapArray[] = new int[array.length];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
         swapArray[i]=array[array.length-1];
         System.out.print(" " + swapArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this just copy `7`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want reverse an array :

With Commons.Lang, you could simply use

```
int array[] = new int[4];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 4;
array[2] = 3;
array[3] = 7;

ArrayUtils.reverse(array);
// For print output
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
// Print output [7, 3, 4, 1]
```